# javax ws rs internalServerErrorException validation

Tags: java, cxf

I get this error when I am trying to test a Rest webservice.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;
javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException.&lt;init&gt;(InternalServerErrorException.java:126)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toInternalServerErrorException(SpecExceptions.java:79)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toInternalServerErrorException(ExceptionUtils.java:113)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.convertExceptionToResponseIfPossible(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:227)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:215)
org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:77)
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:197)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:149)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:290)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
```

NB:Using Jboss 6 and cxf version=3.1.8 .

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: there is something wrong with library version

Comment: Thank you Ravi,please which version i have to use?

Comment: which version of the JAX-RS API do you use?